# LNK2005 happen when include .h file in .c file

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header, stack, lnk2005

I am trying to implement a Stack in a program using C language. I separate them into 3 file.

First, stack.h file. It include some essential declaration and function such as Pop, Push for a stack. 
Second, stack.c file. It is a file implement the function inside stack.h file. In my case, I implement my stack using a dynamic array.
Third, main.c file. It is where I use Stack to do some calculation.

However, I get LNK2005(...already defined in ...obj) compile error at the end. I know this error would happen when there exist a multiple times of definition. However, I saw many example with same function name in .h/.c file but didn't cause a error.

Here is the error log:

```
LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found
LNK2005 _CreateStack already defined in main.obj
LNK2005 _IsEmpty already defined in main.obj
LNK2005 _Pop already defined in main.obj
LNK2005 _Push already defined in main.obj
LNK2005 _StackDepth already defined in main.obj
```

Thanks for you kindly attention.
Here is my stack.h file.

```
typedef struct Stack Stack;

Stack* CreateStack();
void Push(Stack *s, char InputString);
void Pop(Stack *s);
int StackDepth(Stack *s);
int IsEmpty(Stack *s);
```

Here is my stack.c file.

```
#include "stack.h"

typedef struct Stack{
    .....
    .....
}

Stack* CreateStack(){
    ......
};

void Push(Stack *s, char InputString){
    ....
    ....
}

void Pop(Stack *s){
    ....
};

int StackDepth(Stack *s){
    ....
};

int IsEmpty(Stack *s){
    ....
};
```

Here is my main.c file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"stack.c"
#include"stack.h"

int main(){
    ....
    ....
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you [edit] your question to show the actual link error? and drop the semicolons at the end of your function definitions, they're useless.

Comment: Thank you for you attention. Well edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included your C file in your main file.
The `#include` directive tells the pre-processor to textually paste the entire content of the file specified into the location where the `#include` directive is. This means that your function implementations from the `stack.c` file are now compiled both as part of your `stack.c` file and your `main.c` file - implemented twice, as your linker tells you.
The compiler can't deal with ambiguity - it there are 2 matching functions for a call, it returns an error instead of randomly choosing one of them.

You should never `#include` C files, only headers (.h) files.

Comment: Thanks. Really learn something on this. Include only "stack.h" perfectly solved my question.